# Masstransit RabbitMq PublisherConfirmation default value

Tags: masstransit

Does anybody know what is default value for PublisherConfirmation on masstransit?

According to [this link](https://github.com/tenor/RestBus.Benchmarks/pull/5) it seems PublisherConfirmation is false by default.

But I wanted to make sure it is false and I have to turn it on whenever I want to have gaurantee of message persistance.

Also any idea of performance impact of turning on this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it is `true`. You can see the actual line of code where it is configured below:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/Configuration/Configurators/ConfigurationHostSettings.cs#L34

Keep in mind, if it is set to false, there is zero guarantee that a message sent/published actually arrived at the broker.